# Modifying an object inside a class leads to an error

Tags: python-2.7, class, object, tree, runtime-error

I am a beginner in Python and I am trying to understand trees better. Why can't I add nodes inside the function `f` below? I would expect that the final print returns the value `2` instead of an error that `f(test)` in `None`.

```
class Testcls(object):
        def __init__(self,data):
            self.data= data
            self.children = []

        def add_child(self,obj):
            self.children.append(obj)

def f(test):
        data1 = test.data+1
        test.add_child(Testcls(data1))

test = Testcls(1)
print f(test).data
```

Answer (score 0):

Final print in your case should actually return an error. Function `f` doesn't return anything (hence the `None` if you type `print f(test)`. To add children using `f` you can add a return statement:

```
def f(test):
    data1 = test.data+1
    test.add_child(Testcls(data1))
    return test
```

Which now returns the object `test` which you can further access and process,

```
f(test)
print test.children[0].data
```

Since it actually returns the `test` object you can also call it and use it directly:

```
print (f(test).children)[0].data
```

You don't have to have a `return` statement either - `f` will still change the object you're sending to it. In case you don't want to return the object, you just need to call the function separately and only then use `test` like shown in the second code snippet.